# JSON object value from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am using JSON in PHP, and now I need to access it from JavaScript. How do I pass a JSON object to JavaScript?

```
<?php
    $array = array("a"=>"Caucho", "b"=>"Resin", "c"=>"Quercus");
    $json = json_encode($array);
>
```

where My.js has:

```
showAll(){
    alert("Show All Json Objects");
    // How do I get the JSON value here?
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Ajax as your method to download the JSON, you would echo the result of the json_encode:

```
<?php
    $array = array("a"=>"Caucho", "b"=>"Resin", "c"=>"Quercus");

    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

And then within your call back event, you'd eval the response:

```
var obj = eval('(' + req.ResponseText + ')');
for(var i in obj) {
    alert(i + ': ' + obj[i]);
}
```

Assuming that you have an [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) object with the name `req`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$array = array("a"=>"Caucho", "b"=>"Resin", "c"=>"Quercus");
$json = json_encode($array);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myjson = <?php echo $json; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Actually this is the best answer of all, you can put JSON data directly in javascript like in answer, it's documented on [official json page](http://www.json.org/js.html). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could request the JSON data with AJAX or you could pass the data from PHP to JavaScript as a JavaScript variable:

```
$array = array("a"=>"Caucho", "b"=>"Resin", "c"=>"Quercus");
$json = json_encode($array);

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'var myJson = "' . $json . '";';
echo '</script>';
```

edit: you have to eval the json string, otherwise you will just have a string not a object...

Off course keeping in mind all the guidelines about mixing PHP/HTML/JavaScript...

Comment: I would submit a +1 for doing it via ajax instead, since you can then simply eval the returned json snippet and you don't have to worry about mixing php/javascript/html.