# Passing JSON from PHP to a JavaScript variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, cordova

I'm making an aplication with phonegap and I'm stuck trying to send JSON data from the PHP on the server to JavaScript on the device. I want to do something like:

```
var JSON = '{ "Table" : ' + "http://www.hel.net/LoadDB.php=?table=exhibitions" +  '}';
```

the php works fine and returns somethig like:

```
"[{"id":"1","name":"Art for everyone","image":null,"name2":"June 29, 2013: 11:00am.","description":"With reservation\r\nFree entrance","description2":null}]"
```

I want that result in a javascript variable to work later with:

```
var obj = eval ("(" + JSON + ")");
document.getElementById("rName").innerHTML=obj.Table[1].name;
document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML=obj.Table[1].name2;
```

---

What I want to do is something like:

```
var JSON = '{ "Table" : ' + "http://www.hel.net/LoadDB.php=?table=exhibitions" +  '}';
var obj = eval ("(" + JSON + ")");
document.getElementById("rName").innerHTML=obj.Table[1].name;
document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML=obj.Table[1].name2;
```

How can I make the first line work? is it possible to make the first line work?
PS. I do not have much experience with JSON arrays.

---

---

### Ok I tried ajax and works, I used:

```
console.log("before"); 

var jqxhr = $.ajax( "http://www.hel.com/LoadDB.php?table=exhibitions" )
            .done(function(data) { console.log(data); })
            .fail(function() { console.log("error"); })
            .always(function() { console.log("complete"); });

console.log("after");
```

### more info in:

[api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to create and read JSON, don't try to do it by hand.

Comment: On the PHP side have you looked at json_encode() for returning JSON to the caller.

Comment: Just realized this is a duplicate: [json-object-value-from-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460322/)

Comment: Looks like my question. My problem is not evaluating the JSON is getting the response from the PHP, later I will evaluate it. I already use .get and .getJSON, didn't work. Something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

PHP: (json.php)

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/json");

    //the data format your question mentioned
    $data = array("Table"=>array(array("id"=>"1","name"=>"Art for everyone","image"=>null,"name2"=>"June 29, 2013","description"=>"With reservation\r\nFree entrance","description2"=>null)));

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Front-end:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.get("json.php",function(json){
        alert(json.Table[0].name);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: In the dbSelect.js I’m coding:

`console.log("before");
 $.get("http://www.hel.net/LoadDB.php=?table=exhibitions",
  function(json){
   console.log(json.table[0].name);
   console.log("in code"); 
  }
 );<br/>
console.log("after");`

In the log I receive the “before” and the “after” but never the “in code”. I think the problem is something else.

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need is `var obj = <?php echo $myjsonencodedvar; ?>`

or

`var obj = <?php echo json_encode($myarray_or_object); ?>`

Since I said "I think..." I decided to test it out. I found the following dump() function here on SO.

```
$arr=array(1,'biscuit'=>'gravy',3,4,5);
$json=json_encode($arr);
?>
<script>
  j=<?php echo $json; ?>;
 document.write(dump(j));

 function dump(obj) {
    var out = '';
    for (var i in obj) {
        out += i + ": " + obj[i] + "\n";
    }

    return out;
}
</script>
```

output:

```
0: 1 biscuit: gravy 1: 3 2: 4 3: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

using JSONP (no callbacks), and on the client side use $.getJSON() it will parse it from json string to js object.